# Is it secure to store a random value as session "key" in a table?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm building a site with user accounts for the first time. I'm in the process of making user login secure. On registration I hash the password before saving it, then on login If the pass is correct I save a cookie with the user info with setCookie.

Right now hijacking an account is as simple as modifying the cookie values. I want to make the site secure but most options I'm reading about seem too be too complex and I want to use something I can do myself. I've reading a couple of tutorials and have a basic idea of how to do it but don't know how secure it is.

My idea is to make a table for sessions and store the userid + a random value, save a cookie with both and check on every page load both values against the table and renew them if they are correct. This seems simple to make and would work even if the user logs in in from different places but I don't know how secure is it. The cookies would be visible but I don't see any way of hijacking the session unless somebody stole the cookie and used it before it renewed.

Is this secure? What other simple approach could I use?

Comment: If somebody stole has _that kind_ of access to you DB then your screwed either way. Just store the cookie in the database and make sure your database is secured.

Comment: @pst, really? It seems to defy the definition of a "number used *once*".

Comment: @ElYobo I originally took "renew them if they are correct" as a regeneration of the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not store the username in a session variable? The client stores a random ID and presents this to the server. The server then matches this with the username (which the server has locally). **Only the server can see the username.** It's also really easy to code and PHP creates the random ID and gives it to the client for you. Additionally, if the user changes the ID to something else, there's very little chance of them stumbling upon another ID that exists and is in use by another user logged in.

```
session_start();

//setting the username after they log in
$_SESSION['username'] = $username;

//retrieving the username
//this will work from any file as long as they are on the same server for the same domain
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
```

Comment: I was using this until recently. I didn't know it was secure. The problem is that is hard to make it work with many domains using the same source, which was the case in my previous site so I switched to setcookie(). Is this really secure? What happens if somebody copies the cookie?

Comment: I mean is the random ID easily accessed? Anyway I don't want to make it bulletproof just relatively secure. I'll probably choose this unless something else comes up.

Comment: @Liso22 Yes, this is very secure. I want to emphasize that only the server knows the username. The client has a random ID and, when presented to the server, the server matches it to the username. Also, yes, the random ID is easily accessed. There's really no way of preventing someone from copying the ID and using it. You need a way of tracking the user, and when you give ANY information to a client you should fully expect it to be viewed by the user. Perhaps you can only allow one IP address to use a cookie at a time.

Comment: Using the session is perfectly secure.  What problem do you have with multiple domains?  The cookie with the session ID is only sent to one domain (unless you go out of your way to work around that).

Comment: Great, thanks you both for the info. About the multiple domains the problem was that I was using two different domains and SESSION didn't work at all, so I had to directly use COOKIES. I couldn't manage to make SESSION work cross domain.